# Why does "reinterpret_cast" not work as expected on template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, reinterpret-cast, non-type

I have the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct MyStruct {
    int member;
} crake;

#define GPIOA               ( 0x40000000)

template <typename T, crake* Ptr>
struct MyTemplate {
    void doSomething() {
        Ptr->member = 42;
    }
};


int main() {
    crake* ptr = reinterpret_cast<crake*>(GPIOA);
    MyTemplate<MyStruct, reinterpret_cast<crake*>(GPIOA)> instance;
    instance.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

and I compiled it with C++20.Interestingly I get an error on the line

`MyTemplate<MyStruct, reinterpret_cast<crake*>(GPIOA)> instance;`

but not on the line before, where I do the same thing, namely reinterpret casting an integer to a pointer.

The exact error message says:

```
"error: ‘reinterpret_cast’ from integer to pointer
   29 |     MyTemplate<MyStruct, reinterpret_cast<crake*>(GPIOA)> instance;"
```

My goal is to get the address of a struct defined as a constant value (with `#define`) as a non-type template parameter. I know this would crash, but in reality, there is a peripheral behind the address, and writing to it is ok. So I assume, I need to use a const variable but  I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: OT: Why are you using `typedef` for C++ structures? All structure (and class) tag names are also type-names.

Comment: A `reinterpret_cast` cannot be resolved at compile time. Well, not if addresses are involved.

Comment: Also why are you `#define`ing your constants instead of just making a `constexpr crake* = 0x40000000;`?

Comment: You have to read the whole error, not just the first line: `error: '1073741824' is not a valid template argument for 'crake*' {aka 'MyStruct*'} because it is not the address of a variable`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the whole template-thing anyway? `auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(GPIOA); ptr->doSomething();` if you can add the member function to `MyStruct`? Otherwise, inherit from it: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8rjEbx5bn)

Comment: "So I assume, I need to use a const variable but I wanted to avoid that." why do you want to avoid that ?

Comment: In C++ you don't need the `typedef struct ... name` dance. `struct crake { ... };` works just fine. In C you'd have to write `struct crake*` etc.; in C++ all you need is `crake*`.

Answer (score 8):

Template arguments like in:

```cpp
MyTemplate<MyStruct, reinterpret_cast<crake*>(GPIOA)>
```

... have to be constant expressions. [`reinterpret_cast` cannot be used in constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions).
In this case, the problem with allowing it would be that you are creating a pointer to an object that doesn't exist at compile time, so the template argument is somewhat meaningless.
The memory which exists at compile time is different from the memory at runtime.

However, you can pass an address as a template argument, and perform the conversion at runtime:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct crake {
    int member;
};

inline constexpr std::uintptr_t GPIOA = 0x40000000;

template <typename T, std::uintptr_t Address>
struct MyTemplate {
    static inline crake * const Ptr = reinterpret_cast<crake*>(Address);
    void doSomething() {
        Ptr->member = 42;
    }
};


int main() {
    MyTemplate<crake, GPIOA> instance;
    instance.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

This has no additional overhead compared to the original code, and compiles to:

```cpp
main:
   mov dword ptr [0x40000000], 42
   xor eax, eax
   ret
```

See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/e6dvTT77f).